# Formula in neuralnet classifier and trained weight matrix

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using the neuralnet package in R to fit the neural net classifier to my data.

```
net <- neuralnet(Y1+Y2+Y3~X1+X2+X3, binary.data, hidden=45,
rep=10, err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE)
```

Now my issue is that my binary.data frame has 300 feature vectors and 10 output classes. So if I manually add those targets and features into my formula in neuralnet classifier then it would be very tedious.

Also where would be the trained weights after fitting the data?

Since I fit neural net with 45 hidden neurons,300 features and 10 classes so I expect two weight matrices one with dimension 300x45 and other with dimension 45x10?

Where would I find those weight matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the formula you can use something like this (I'm using `lm` but it is the same principle for any function using the formula interface):

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol = 100))
dat$y <- rnorm(NROW(dat))
mF <- formula(paste("y ~" , paste(names(dat)[-101], collapse = "+")))
lm(mF, data = dat)
```

So you generate the `formula` automatically and you do not have to hardcode the whole formula yourself but you can generate it. Another option would be to use the `.` qualifier, which reads as *everything else not yet present in the formula*.

From `?formula`:

> There are two special interpretations of ‘.’ in a formula.  The
>        usual one is in the context of a ‘data’ argument of model fitting
>        functions and means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’:
>        see ‘terms.formula’.  In the context of ‘update.formula’, *only*,
>        it means ‘what was previously in this part of the formula’.

Comment: But output is also in the form of multivariate like y1+y2+....y10? Not just single y.By the way I got inspired from your code.

Comment: Well, that should not be too tricky to solve: `dat$y2 <- rnorm(NROW(dat)); formula(paste(paste(names(dat)[101:102], collapse = "+"), "~", paste(names(dat)[1:100], collapse = "+")))`

Comment: just a little bit hint would suffice for me.also how could I find trained weights fitted by the model? for RSNNS package it was easy but problem was Bias could not be added in mlp function?

Comment: Could you accept an answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `neuralnet()` unfortunately needs you to specify the formula inside the function. You can specify it by using 'paste' function as demonstrated in @thothal's answer. If you want to avoid this you can use the `RSNNS` package instead of 'neuralnet' where you can present your entire input and output features in form of input/output dataframes.

To view the weights you can use `plot.nn()` or `gwplot()` but that doesn't give you matrix output. Again `RSNNS` package allows you to extract weights in form of a matrix by using `$getCompleteWeightMatrix` suffix against your neural net object.

Comment: issue is bias cannot be added in mlp function  inside RSNNS package?

Comment: You **can**  specify your formula in a programmatic way as shown in my answer.

Comment: You can do so by using `$setUnitDefaults` and specify bias... or you can also add bias by just having an additional input vector of '1' along with the rest of the 300...

Comment: @Gaurav your idea is good what we should add an additional vector of 1's in the feature space but the problem is that bias is also added in the hidden layer how that can be done?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed When you add a constant input of '1' through an additional vector, the weights on the synapses associated with this additional vector will indirectly become your bias in the hidden and output layer both. You don't need to do anything more to add bias.

Comment: any reference or proof you can give me please?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed This is basic neural network math... A bias of a neural network is nothing more than a constant to shift the activation function curve which is the same as providing a constant input of value 1 and then having it multiplied with a weight (this weight is eventually optimized during training)... Check out wikipedia article example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Example) where the bias of 1 (which is depicted as x0 as a constant input of value 1)...